# An integral transform computation

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, special-functions

In Erdelyi, [Tables of Integral Transforms](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf),  p. 344 Section 7.2.
they note that
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}  s^{\nu}  e^{\alpha s^2} x^{-s} \, ds
  = 2^{-\nu/2} \pi^{-1/2} \alpha^{-\nu/2-1/2} \exp\left( - \frac{ (\log x)^2}{8 \alpha }\right)
  D_{\nu} \left( \frac{\log x}{ (2 \alpha)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right).
\end{align}
where $D_{\nu}$ is a  Parabolic Cylinder Function, defined on
page 386 in the same book.

Does anyone know how to prove this result?

Comment: One approach is to attempt to prove the Mellin transform $$s^{\nu} e^{\alpha s^2}=\int\limits_0^\infty 2^{-\nu/2} \pi^{-1/2} \alpha^{-\nu/2-1/2} \exp\left(-\frac{(\log x)^2}{8 \alpha}\right) D_{\nu}\left(\frac{\log x}{(2 \alpha)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right) x^{s-1}\,dx$$ where I believe the integrand on the right side can be simplified slightly using the substitution $y=\frac{\log x}{(2 \alpha)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ in which case $x=e^{\sqrt{2 \alpha}\, y}$.

Answer (score 4):

This should be equivalent to [[DLMF 12.5.6](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.5.E6)] (use the translation $D_\nu(z) = U(-\frac{1}{2}-\nu,z)$ [[DLMF 12.2.5](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.2.E5)]). The cited references for the proofs are Miller (1955, §4) and Whittaker (1902).

> - *Miller, J. C. P. (ed.)*, [**Tables of Weber parabolic cylinder functions. Giving solutions of the differential equation $d^2y/dx^2+\bigl({1\over 4}x^2-a\bigr)y=0$**](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.16#info), Computed by Scientific Computing Service Limited. (National Physical Laboratory.) London: Her Majesty’s Stationary Office, 233 p. (1955). [ZBL0067.10204](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0067.10204).
> - *Whittaker, E. T.*, [**On the functions associated with the parabolic cylinder in harmonic analysis.**](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s1-35.1.417), London M. S. Proc. 35, 417-427 (1903). [ZBL34.0520.01](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:34.0520.01).